# How to handle NameError in Python

Tags: python, import, module, nameerror

This error just started today, and I can't figure out how to rectify the situation.

Let's say I run the following script:

```
name = "Bob"
```

Then in the interpreter, I can type:

```
>>> name
'Bob'
```

However, if my script is:

```
import some_module_I_just_made_up #It's in the same directory as my script
name = "Bob"
```

Then in the interpreter, I get the following:

```
>>> name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your main script again (the one that contains the import)?

Comment: Can you post your code that's actually generating this error? Either the error code doesn't match what you've sent or you need to show what's in `some_module_I_just_made_up`

Comment: Are you running a saved file that contains your script, and then opening an interpreter? Or by "script" do you mean you're entering all these commands at the interpreter? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import your script from the interpreter.

```
>>> import myscript
```

Assuming `myscript` has the code:

```
import some_module_I_just_made_up
name = "Bob"
```

Then you can call

```
>>> myscript.name
```

and have it output the name. The interpreter doesn't know what `name` is until it's in a module or defined in the interpreter.

If you just want the name variable and nothing else, you can do this:

```
>>> from myscript import name
>>> name
```

Comment: Just `name` won't work. You have to use `myscript.name`.

Comment: @Matthias Ah, you are correct. Fixed answer to reflect